# 2 Properties in One Binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, multibinding

Can I combine 2 elements in one biding?

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Fill="Black" x:Name="dot1" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="124" Canvas.Top="133"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Black" x:Name="dot2" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="40"/>
    <Line Stroke="Black" x:Name="line1" 
          X1="{Binding ElementName=dot1, Path=(Canvas.Left)}" 
          Y1="{Binding ElementName=dot1, Path=(Canvas.Top)}"

          X2="{Binding ElementName=dot2, Path=(Canvas.Left)}" 
          Y2="{Binding ElementName=dot2, Path=(Canvas.Top)}"
          />
</Canvas>
```

I need not only to bind the Line Start and End Points to the dots **Left** and **Right**, but the addition of (**`Left + Width / 2`**) and (**`Top + Height / 2`**) (centers).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and implement the formula in a [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

**Edit:**

Something like this where only X1 uses the MultiBindingand the rest are unchanged.

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Fill="Black" x:Name="dot1" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="124" Canvas.Top="133"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Black" x:Name="dot2" Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="40"/>
    <Line Stroke="Black" x:Name="line1" 
    Y1="{Binding ElementName=dot1, Path=(Canvas.Top)}"

    X2="{Binding ElementName=dot2, Path=(Canvas.Left)}" 
    Y2="{Binding ElementName=dot2, Path=(Canvas.Top)}">
        <Line.X1>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding Path="(Canvas.Top)"/>
                <Binding Path="(Canvas.Left)"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Line.X1>
    </Line>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: As I can see, there is a <Multibinding> node added in textBox... But in a <Line> element I didn't achieve to add this element...

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to multiple properties using a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx).

There are several examples and tutorials on this out there - e.g. [this](http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/multibinding-in-wpf.html) and [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings) seems to tell you what you need to know.